# Paginar una tabla mysql con DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, datatables

Tengo una tabla que trae datos de mysql en PHP, y tengo los Scripts de DataTable, pero no me pagina la tabla.
Que debo hacer para que me pagine la tabla,
Gracias de antemano.

```
<table>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href="../library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../library/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../library/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../library/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../library/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../library/datatables/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/fontawesome-free-5.0.4/fontawesome-free-5.0.4/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/fontawesome-free-5.0.4/fontawesome-free-5.0.4/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf8" type="text/javascript" src="../library/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../library/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/datatables/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/js1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tablasExp').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $consulta5 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
        echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
        echo "<div class='panel-heading'>";
        echo "Usuarios";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";

        echo "<table width='100%' class='table table-fixed table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-hover' id='tablasExp' style='font-size: 11px;'>";
        echo "<thead style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>";
        echo "<tr style='font-size: 13px; font-style: normal;'>";
        echo "<th style='text-align: center;'>Nombre</th>";
        echo "<th style='text-align: center;'>Identificacion</th>";
        echo "<th style='text-align: center;'>Nombre Usuario</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";

        $matriz = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta5);
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($matriz)) {
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $fila[1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fila[2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fila[3] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
        }
    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: El plugin datatable pagina las tablas que tienen como id="table", tu le pusiste a la tabla id="tablasExp", has el cambio y me cuentas que tal te va.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La etiqueta tbody tiene que abrir antes del while y cerrar después del cierre del while.

By: [FedericoG](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/56171/federicog)

Answer (score 1):

Las etiquetas `<tbody></tbody>` se deben abrir y cerrar antes del `while`, sino las crearás muchas veces y eso ya no lo reconoce el `HTML`, adicional, te falta cerrar el `</table>` y el cierre de los `</div>` también están en un lugar erroneo

Intenta con esto

```
<body>
    <?php
        $consulta5 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
        echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
        echo "<div class='panel-heading'>";
        echo "Usuarios";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";

        echo "<table width='100%' class='table table-fixed table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-hover' id='tablasExp' style='font-size: 11px;'>";
        echo "<thead style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>";
        echo "<tr style='font-size: 13px; font-style: normal;'>";
        echo "<th style='text-align: center;'>Nombre</th>";
        echo "<th style='text-align: center;'>Identificacion</th>";
        echo "<th style='text-align: center;'>Nombre Usuario</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        $matriz = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta5);
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($matriz)) {            
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $fila[1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fila[2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fila[3] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";            
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    ?>          
</body>
```

Si se te solucionó puedes marcarlo como **Respondido** :D

Answer (score 0):

Te falta la etiqueta de cierre de la tabla, antes de la del body.

```
    </table>
  </body>
```

También faltan cerrar otras div que se abren antes de la tabla.

Editado:

La etiqueta tbody tiene que abrir antes del while y cerrar después.

Comment: No si la tienen es que no las puse

Comment: ¿Probaste con una versión estática de la página, que tenga una versión de la tabla en html no generada por php? De esa forma podés ver si el problema está con DataTable o con el php. Como consejo, no pongas ejemplos erróneos (por ejemplo, con etiquetas faltantes), dificulta el diagnóstico del problema.

Comment: Si ya lo probé y si funciona la tabla sola en html.

Comment: La etiqueta tbody tiene que abrir antes del while y cerrar después.

Comment: Si era eso muchas gracias.

Comment: Y la etiqueta table tiene que cerrar antes que las etiquetas div.

Comment: ¿Puedes marcarlo como respondido? Gracias!